# Post visibility for specific users

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

I'm about to start programming some kind of website which works like this:

User logs in, and if he's a normal user(not an admin) he'll be presented with some posts that relate to his kind of account(Accouns are menaged and given by admin)

What admin does is creates those posts and while creating it he says who will have access to seeing that post (e.g checks a user who will see it , or several users or maybe all users will be able to see it)

My problem is , what kind of tables should i create in my database and with what columns.
My first plan was to have ofc:
 1) table of users
 2) table of posts
 **3) table of permissions**
table of permission would have fields **([postID], and then fileds like [user1],[user2]....[userN])** and example row in the table would look like 
**21|true|true|false|true|....|true|** which indicates that those users will be able to see the post. And those fields [userN] could be created dinamically as new users are created
I'm asking for an opinion on this kind of db, and ofcourse your idea for doing this db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create table users
(   id int not null auto_increment primary key,
    fullName varchar(100) not null
);

create table posts
(   id int not null auto_increment primary key,
    postName varchar(200) not null
);

create table post_user_junction
(   id int not null auto_increment primary key,
    userId int not null,
    postId int not null,
    UNIQUE (userId,postId),
    -- foreign key (FK) referential integrity:
    FOREIGN KEY (userId) REFERENCES users(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (postId) REFERENCES posts(id)
);

insert post_user_junction (userId,postId) values (1,1);
-- ooops, Error 1452, FK violation, user and post do not exist yet

insert users(fullName) values ('a');
insert posts(postName) values ('a');

-- works:
insert post_user_junction (userId,postId) values (1,1);

-- do it again, does not work, already there:
insert post_user_junction (userId,postId) values (1,1);
```

There you go, you should be out of the gates with the above, to at least start.

Comment: thanks for your reply but what would happen if I want some post to be visible by 2 or more users but not everyone? Should I add row in the table for every "post-user" relationship? I just tought that would be a bit redundunt but if thats a way to go...?

Comment: now in `post_user_junction ` you can add a `rights` column with values such as READONLY, UPDATE, etc if you want. Or don't add it and if junction row exists there, the user has all rights. Whatever.